# Why EclipseIDe is not displaying Console icon in the view sections

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, eclipse-luna

In my Eclipse Luna Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

> Why EclipseIDe is not displaying Console icon in the view sections?

I am getting the following Sections to view such as Javadoc,declarations and Problems section.

I am not able to see Console section so that i could see my code how many errors it has.I think it had been disabled.

What I did?

I searched google and various stack overflow previous questions and they could not Ans my question.Please help Thankx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'Window > Show View > Console' to show the console view.

If 'Console' is not visible there use 'Window > Show View > Other...' and look for 'Console' in the 'General' section.

Answer (score 0):

randomly did such things as (several times):

1) Project->Clean...,
2) close and open Eclipse again,
3) Run As...

And it started to work again, without changing configuration.

Comment: Shanar I already tried it.I did it again it is something else.It think Compiler has been hidden nd i am not getting a button to make it view